# I am trying to click on quick look in amazon using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to automate `amazon.in` where the Quick Look button is not clickable. For Quick Look to appear we have to hover over on product. I don't know if my XPath or CSS selector is wrong so possibly want to know an effective way for finding XPath

```
WebElement productElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'a-section octopus-pc-item-hue-shield')])[1]"));
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(productElement).build().perform();
WebElement quickLookButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Quick look']/ancestor::a"));
quickLookButton.click();
```

Comment: Still unable to repro _Quick look button_ without logging in and even with logging in. Am I missing something?

Comment: For reproducing quick look no need to login for example. On Amazon click Men fashion then Shirts. Now you will see product list hover your mouse pointer on products you will see Quick Look

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned it to the variable hover, but then you're trying to use actions instead of hover in the following line to move the mouse to the productElement.

```
WebElement productElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[contains(@class,'a-section octopus-pc-item-hue-shield')])[1]"));
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);
hover.moveToElement(productElement).build().perform();
WebElement quickLookButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Quick look']/ancestor::a"));
quickLookButton.click();
```